# Poor performance - SVG animations

Tags: performance, animation, svg, two.js

So I'm creating some animations for a client and I've been playing with two.js because I liked its SVG capabilities. Unfortunately I'm having issues with performance.

I'm plotting 100 circles on the screen. Each circle contains 6 further circles for a total of 700 circles being rendered on load.

The circles react to mouse movements on the x-axis and cascade slowly downwards on the y-axis.

Currently in Chrome its only running at around 32FPS. In Firefox it barely even works!

I've also tried two.js's webgl renderer but while there is a slight performance increase, the elements just don't look as good as SVG.

The source is here: https://github.com/ashmore11/verifyle/tree/develop

path to file: src/coffee/elements/dots

Let me know if there's any more info I can provide.

Comment: SMIL or CSS animations will likely give better performance than javascript animations.

Comment: your dev link goes to the source code...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you've made is very beautiful!

Hmmm, so there are many factors as to why the performance isn't as stellar as you'd like.

1. The **size** of the drawable area matters (i.e: the `<svg />` or `<canvas />` element). The bigger the area the more pixels to render.
2. The **amount** of elements added to the DOM. Yes there are 100 dots, but each dot is comprised of many elements.
3. Of those elements the amount of **changes** an element has on any given frame.
4. Finally, of the elements changing how many **operations** (i.e: `opacity`, `scale`, `translation`, etc.)

These considerations compound in most computer generated imagery to affect real-time rendering. The goal is basically to reduce the load on any one of those dimensions and see if it's enough to give you the performance you're looking for. You're gonna have to get creative, but there are options. Here are a few things off the top of my head that you can do to try to speed things up:

- Reducing the amount of shapes will make it run faster ^^
- For something like this `Two.Types.canvas` *might* be fastest.
- Instead of moving each dot split the `translation` into 2 or 3 groups and move them based on the container groups. Kind of like a *foreground* and *background* parallax.
- If you're sticking with `Two.Types.svg` try animating only a handful of dots on any given frame. This way you're not doing entire traversal of the whole scene every frame and each dot isn't animating every frame.

Pseudo code for this might look like:

```
// ... some array : dots inferred ... //

var now = Date.now();
var index, length = 12;

two.bind('update', function() {
  for (var i = index; i < Math.min(index + 12, dots.length); i++) {
    var dot = dots[i];
    dot.scale = (Math.sin(now / 100) + 1) / 4 + 0.75;
  }
  index = (index + 12) % dots.length;
});
```

- If none of these are giving you anything substantial you're looking for than I would highly recommend turning in each `Dot` into a texture and drawing those textures either directly through `canvas2d` or with `WebGL` and a library. [Three.js](http://threejs.org) will be able to render hundreds of thousands of these: http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_particles_sprites You'll have to rethink a lot of how the texture itself is generated and how the opacity varies between the lines and of course it'll *look* slightly different as you described in your question. Bitmap is different from Vector >_<

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed answer @jonobr1. Unfortunately the client is pushing for even more dots : ( Last night I ported everything to pixi.js to take advantage of webgl with a canvas fallback and the performance is where I'd like it to be now. I really do love your library though and will be 100% using it in the future for personal projects of mine. Thanks for all the hard work.

Comment: There is also performance issue when animating, transforming SVG elements. They trigger painting. Always. See: http://www.crmarsh.com/svg-performance (The article is from 2014. Nothing has changed since then. Please, correct me if Im wrong.)