# How to create depth in two.js

Tags: javascript, two.js

I have recently been learning how to use two.js and I want to make a circle orbit around another object like a planet. Since it needs to pass behind the object its orbiting around, I'm trying to dynamically change the circle's size as it moves to create the illusion of depth. I saw another overflow question about changing size in two.js using a matrix and tried to apply it here but I cannot get the size changes to match sync with the orbital motion. I would appreciate any help.

JS bin (since it needs two.js library this doesn't produce anything at first but I made it for the convenience of anyone who wants to help): https://jsbin.com/rugakojivu/edit?html,output

```
<html>
<head>
<script src = "two.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id = "frame"></div>
<script>
var el = document.getElementById("frame");
var two = new Two({fullscreen:true}).appendTo(el);
var bigAngle = 0,
smallAngle  = 0,
distance   = 10,
radius     = 50,
orbit      = 200,
orbits     = two.makeGroup();
var  offset = 300;

function getPositions(angle, orbit) {
return {
    x: Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180) * orbit,
    y: Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180) * orbit
};
}

var pos = getPositions(bigAngle,orbit),
big = two.makeCircle(pos.x+offset,pos.y+offset,radius);

big.stroke="#123456";
big.linewidth=7;
big.fill="#194878";

big._matrix.manual=true;

two.bind("update",function(frameCount){
  var pos = getPositions(bigAngle++,orbit);
  big.translation.x=pos.x+offset;
  big.translation.y=pos.y+offset;
});

  two.bind("update",function(frameCount,timeDelta){
  var sx=Math.sin(frameCount/200);
  big._matrix
    .identity()
    .translate(big.translation.x, big.translation.y)
    .rotate(big.rotation)
    .scale(sx);

    });
    two.play();


    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your circle doesn't smoothly grow and shrink because the browser can't render it as fast as you need it.

This is from [Two.js.org](https://two.js.org/#draw-animation):

> `two.play()` calls `two.update()` at 60fps. This rate, however, will
>   slowdown if there's too much content to render per frame

Whether you use `frameCount` or `timeDelta` this will happen.

The answer in [Poor performance - SVG animations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32386243/3200552) reviews some strategies to improve performance in two.js. 
Additionally you could recreate this using CSS animations with @keystrokes to get the same animation.

I think this is pretty close to what you were doing:
https://jsfiddle.net/merhoo/skmz279w/1/

Hope that helps!